# iOS 5 ScrollView Adding SubViews Causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios5, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

ARC, iOS 5, XCode 4.2

I am trying to implement a paged scroll view with a page control (similar to the Home screen), and I can't seem to get it to work.  The relevant code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [scroll setDelegate:self];
    [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(2 * [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
    [scroll setPagingEnabled:YES];

    pageControl.currentPage = 0;
    pageControl.numberOfPages = 2;

    UIView* view = [[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VALID_ID_1"] view];
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);

    [scroll addSubview:view];

    UIView *aView = [[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VALID_ID_2"] view];
    aView.frame = CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);

    [scroll addSubview:aView];
}
```

Calling the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` method returns a result.

**Things I have tried:**

- Disabling ARC on this particular file
- Using `alloc] init]` on the view controller

**EDIT**: I should probably show the declaration:

```
//MyViewController.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView* scroll;

...

//MyViewController.m
@synthesize scroll;
```

Answer (score 0):

most likely, `scroll` is `nil`. please check..!

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I have added `NSLog(@"SCROLL %@", scroll);`, which results in: `SCROLL <UIScrollView: 0x7243dc0; frame = (0 0; 768 960); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7217240>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>`, so `scroll` is not nil